# closed! jquery get function and callback

Tags: javascript

I have a trigger button on my page that activate to load code from another htmldoc into a div on my page.

Works great like here:
https://blog.kulturbanause.de/2012/12/inhalte-per-ajax-jquery-nachladen/

I take this code:

```
<script>
  function kb_source_2_target() {
    $.get('source.html', function(data) {
      $('#target').html(data);  
    })
  }
</script>
```

Now I want my trigger-button to start a second function after loading the code in the div.

in the loading code there is a div, f.e. class="divtofadeoutafter loading"
i want to trigger now the loading and then the fadeout of an other div in the loaded content.

Can I do this with a callback?

I tried this:

```
<script>
  function kb_source_2_target() {
    $.get('source.html', function(data) {
      $('#target').html(data,
        function callback(){
          $(".divtofadeoutafterloading").fadeOut();
        }
      );    
    })
  }
</script>
```

thanks for any idea
stefan

Comment: There is no callback in html.

Answer (score 1):

There is no callback in [`html()`](https://api.jquery.com/html/) so you just need to do it inline since it is a synchronous operation.

```
function kb_source_2_target() {
  $.get('source.html', function(data) {
    $('#target').html(data)
    $(".divtofadeoutafterloading").fadeOut();
  })
}
```